# How to find the string which begins with the exact word

Tags: java, string, apache-commons-config

I have an app with GUI on gwt. using this gui I'd like to change(and this is the subquestion: how this would be better to change the .properties file(I know how to read properties from them using `org.apache.commons.configuration`, but don't know how to edit(as string or how...))) the .properties file. for example: I've written the following .properties file:

```
################################################################################
# User permissions                                                             #
################################################################################

users = admin, root, guest
users.admin.keywords = admin
users.admin.regexps = test-5, test-7

users.root.keywords = root
users.root.regexps = *

users.guest.keywords = guest
users.guest.regexps = *
```

and so, how to add `keywords` for admin, for example?

**UPD:**
here is my working with config class in which I want to change config file:

```
    public class Config {

    private static final Config ourInstance = new Config();
    private static final CompositeConfiguration prop = new CompositeConfiguration();

    public static Config getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public Config(){
    }

    public synchronized void load() {
        try {
            prop.addConfiguration(new SystemConfiguration());

            System.out.println("Loading /rules.properties");
            final PropertiesConfiguration p = new PropertiesConfiguration();
            p.setPath("/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/DLPServer/src/main/resources/rules.properties");
            p.load();
            prop.addConfiguration(p);

        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final int processors = prop.getInt("server.processors", 1);

        // If you don't see this line - likely config name is wrong
        System.out.println("Using processors:" + processors);
    }

    public void setKeyword(String customerId, String keyword){
        prop.setProperty("users." + customerId + ".keywords", prop.getProperty("users." + customerId + ".keywords") + ", " + keyword);
        prop.
    }

    public void setRegexp(String customerId, String regexp)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            //set the properties value
            prop.setProperty("users.guest.keywords", "keyword");
            prop.setProperty("users.guest.regexps", "regexps");    
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this looks like the best solution. and what if I want some properties to have multiple values, like: `users.guest.keywords = keyword1, keyword2, keyword3`? is it better `prop.setProperty(prop.getString("users." + login + ".keywords") + new keyword)`?

Comment: You can format value as per your convenience and application requirements

Answer (score 1):

Load props with

```
void getPropertiesFromFile( Properties props, String fileName )
{
    try {
        File file = new File( fileName ) ;
        if (!file.exists())
            return ;

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( file ) ;

        try {
            props.load( in ) ;
        } finally {
            in.close() ;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

NOTE: Perhaps, you would want to load them not from a file but with classLoader.getResource(); The code will change slightly.

Then, iterate over names and find what you need

```
for (String name : props.keys) {
   if (name.startWith("users.admin.")) {
       String value = props.get(name);
       ...
   }
}
```

If you are going to modify props during the iteration you should wrap props.keys as follows

```
for (String name : new HashSet(props.keys)) {
```

After you are done, store them

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("abc");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        props.store(fos, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: about the part of code which is in the middle of your post: as I understand I found the string which begins with users.admin and what then? As for me, i've forgot to say: I user `properties props`, but `CompositeConfiguration prop`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your original question.

```
boolean String.startsWith(<prefix>)
```